# Getting error to send email using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using **relay-hosting.secureserver.net** as a smtp server and i am getting following error:
Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, relaying denied from your location [212.78.237.157] (#5.7.1)

Did i need to change smtp setting or any thing else?

Here is code:

```
var mailClient = new SmtpClient();

mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "alerts@mycloudcctv.com", Password = "xyz" };

mailClient.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
mailClient.EnableSsl = false;
mailClient.DeliveryMethod=SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

var mail = new MailMessage("alerts@mycloudcctv.com", "azharmalik3@yahoo.com", "Test Smtp server", "Testing mycloudcctv server") { IsBodyHtml = true };

mailClient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to do the sending?

Answer (score 0):

make sure,

1. you have specified the correct user name and password in Host SMTP Settings section
2. Use a valid email address in your user account,
3. Check are you allowed to send mails from your SMTP server.